# Difference between \`nonexistent_command\` and \``"nonexistent_command"\`

Tags: ruby

Why do `` \`some nonexistent command\` `` and `` `\`"some nonexistent command"\` `` behave differently?

```
irb> \`nonexistent_command\`
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - nonexistent_command
in ``'

irb> \`"nonexistent_command"\`
sh: nonexistent_command: command not found
=> ""
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: The string that you have in the text of the question and the string in the code are different. It is not clear what exactly you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

when you use backticks ` that is telling ruby to go out and try and run that system command. You are getting an "Error no entry" (ENOENT) error back from the operating system which can't find that command or file.

when you use double quotes " you are creating a string and that is no problem.

food for thought: perhaps you mean to use single quotes (which is simply a string that does not get variable interpolation done on it) instead of backticks?

Comment: This is not what I mean. \`non\` and \`"non"\` have different behavior. Why?